# React components not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a mini app to get flight dates prices etc using the Ryanair's API.

I have a component to conditionally render 2 other components based on if there are flights on the day or not, but it's not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import isFlight from './isFlight';
import noFlight from './noFlight';

function FlightCheck({isflight}){
  if(isflight === true){ 
    return <isFlight/>;
  }
  return <noFlight/>;
}
export default FlightCheck;
```

Comment: any errors? what is the problem there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your component names need to start with a capital letter.

```
import IsFlight from './isFlight';
import NoFlight from './noFlight';

<IsFlight/>

<NoFlight/>
```

> This is a JSX tag name convention used to differentiate between built in components and custom components. Built in components start with a lowerCase letter, whereas custom components will start with a upperCase letter